# If else does not work in protractor with coffee script

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, protractor

This piece of code used to work and now it does not. Basically I am trying to check for button or dropdown. If button exists, click button or else click dropdown.

```
describe 'Create a portal', ->
    it 'Create a Portal', ->
        if $('.default-portal-btn').length //check to see button exists
          element(By.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).click()
        else
          element(dropdownPortal).click() //if not click dropdown
          element(createPortal).click()
```

`$('.default-portal-btn').length returns 1` in UI in console and it's not executing the if statement and jumping to else. I don't understand why.

Can someone shed some insight?

Comment: Have you tried consoling the length immediately before the `if`?

Comment: Yes. It's 1 this used to work but it does not go to if statement at all dont know why

Comment: Hmm. I still suspect it to be 0.  Did you put `console.log($('.default-portal-btn').length)` right in the code, (not just typed in the browser console)?

Comment: When I type in browser console, I get 1. But when I do 
console.log($('.default-portal-btn').length) it gives me undefined.

Comment: This is the button: http://puu.sh/k5Rop/745fc4af62.png

Comment: If it was zero I would have suggested waiting for the DOM ready event, but `undefined` is, well, unexpected.

Comment: What is the issue? and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that everything in protractor is a promise - `$('.default-portal-btn')` is a promise that would be resolved into an `ElementFinder` instance. The presence of an element should be checked differently. Please translate the following to coffeescript:

```
browser.isElementPresent($('.default-portal-btn')).then(function (isPresent) {
    if (isPresent) {
        element(by.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).click();
    } else {
        element(dropdownPortal).click();
        element(createPortal).click();
    }
});
```